# Calling a bean through a Javascript Birt Expression

Tags: javascript, java, birt

I am trying to show the contact number (GetExtension) of the current user logged in who is producing a report.

By using the code below I can show the name of the user who is logged on, I place this Javascript  code within Birt's Expression Builder (Dynamic text field). This works:

```
`var result = "USERID";
try {
result = Packages.uk.co.blah.session.Session.getUserID();
} catch (error) {
Packages.java.lang.System.err.println(error);
}
result;`
```

I cannot get the Extension method to show using the same code, adjusted to 'getExtension',

```
`var result = "EXTENSION"; 
try { 
result = Packages.uk.co.blah.session.Session.getExtension(); 
} catch (error) {
Packages.java.lang.System.err.println(error); result;`
```

This did not work so I then tried altering this to the direct path of the package and not session.Session:

```
`var result = "EXTENSION";
try {
result = Packages.uk.co.blah.systemmanagement.personnel.getExtension();
} catch (error) {
Packages.java.lang.System.err.println(error);
}
result;`
```

Again, this just gives the word ‘EXTENSION’.

How can I use getExtension based off the person logged on using getUserID?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your error handling is correct?

What I would do to debug this:

- Remove the try-catch.
- use some debug output to display type(result) and result.
- Use calls to Java's System.err before anything happens, just to see
  that the code is actually executed and that you can output anything
  to System.err.

Note that writing to System.err often behaves like a no-op in Java, because e.g. `javaw.exe` writes the System.out and System.err to *nowhere*.
The same behavior occurs with `eclipse.exe`, whereas `eclipsec.exe` will actually write System.out and System.err to the console.

Comment: Thanks, I will go through these checks next to see what happens.